# How to revert changes made by *.deb

Tags: 13.04, uninstall, deb, gimp

I installed a *.deb on my Ubuntu 13.04 that was probably badly maintained (more of that later). I downloaded it from a download-portal (it was gimpshop_26953.deb from netzwelt.de) and installed via Ubuntu Software Center. The Software Center claimed that the package was of bad quality because the maintainer-mail-adress was missing. I installed anyway (probably a bad idea, lesson learned).

Anyway: How can I get rid of what I installed? It does not show as installed in Ubuntu Software Center, neither can I manage to find anything that makes sense with aptitude (searching for 'gimp').
Software Center told me after the successful installation that "the following applications are run from Terminal: gimp, gimp-2.2, gimp-remote, gimp-2.2-remote, gimptools". Running 'gimp' from Terminal resulted in starting vanilla GIMP 2.2 (which was not the point in installing GimpShop at all). So I now just want to get rid of it and install 2.8 straight away. Problem: It does not start. No error given. I think the old installation is still messing around.

Please please advise how to learn what this pesky *.deb installed and how to uninstall it. I can provide you with the *.deb/link if needed.

Comment: When you installed the *.deb file(s) (*.deb is installing all files ending on .deb if there is many of them) You got the names of the packages?

Comment: @Noel Have you tried to run `sudo apt-get remove gimpshop`? That package is installed under `/usr/local`, so it shouldn't have replaced anything. if you already have Gimp installed you can start it using `/usr/bin/gimp`.

Comment: @Salem I can't believe how stupid I was. Thank you for pointing out the obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use

```
sudo apt-get purge gimpshop
```

which will remove package with its config files. Sometimes you want to get rid of everything that the package brought and AFAIK this is your case.

In the next versions of Ubuntu, when btrfs filesystem will be default, apt-get is integrated with snapshots of btrfs so you can get exactly to the state before the package was installed.

Comment: I chose your answer as it fits better to my case, than my own answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was simply being stupid and not trying the obvious. Of course gimpshop somehow showed nowhere as installed (especially not in aptitude, searching in "Installed packets" for "gimp"), making it no easier.

Yet the obvious thing that I did not try, was

```
sudo apt-get remove gimpshop
```

It did work. I installed GIMP 2.8 from the Software Center afterwards and it launched normal. Why it didn't before, I don't know.

So for future reference: ALWAYS try to apt-get remove the package you installed, no matter which way and how ominous the content seems at first. Topic closed.